# Apache Camel 3（次期メジャーバージョンアップ）に向けて開発者が取り組んでいる大きな機能は何ですか？

Tags: apache-camel

次期メジャーバージョンアップのApache Camel 3 で、「開発者から見て」目玉となる機能は何でしょうか？　Apache Camel 開発者と親しく、現在の取り組みをご存知の方がいれば教えてください。

機能的な面もそうですが、もしも非機能面的なものもありましたらそれもお教えください。

Comment: 「主観的だ」というフィードバックをいただいてますが、あるライブラリのメジャーバージョンアップについて、その注目機能は何か、という質問が主観的な回答しか得られない、という指摘が理解できていません。どんなライブラリも、メジャーバージョンアップをするならそれなりに客観的なコンセンサスの得られた注目機能があるものではないですか？　もし違うなら、具体的にこうすれば良くなる、という改善案を提示いただけますか？

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68630/discussion-between-tadayoshi-sato-and-nekketsuuu)しましょう。

Comment: ご指摘に基づき、こちらにメタ質問を上げました。
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2591/の次期メジャーバージョンアップの目玉機能は何か-という質問は主観的か

Comment: 私自身勘違いしていましたが、SOにはクローズ投票者とその是非について議論する仕組みがないようです。私の疑問はメタに挙げたので、ひとまずこちらは私から「再オープン」の投票をします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camel の開発者メーリングリストを購読し、また定期的にプロジェクトリードの Claus を含む Camel 開発者チーム（の一部）とのオンラインミーティングに参加している者です。私自身も、現在40コミットほど Camel へのコントリビュートがあります。

まず、とりあえず現時点で Camel 3 について出されている様々なアイディアは、こちらにまとめられています。
http://camel.apache.org/camel-30-ideas.html

私が見聞きする限り、一番大きなところは、camel-core のアーキテクチャの刷新になると思います。

現在の camel-core はクラシックな再帰構造でエンジンのパイプラインが実装されているため、メソッド呼び出しのスタックが深くなってしまう問題があります。最近では Node.js や Vert.x、Akka など Reactive Programming が注目されているので、camel-core のエンジンもリアクティブな作りに再構築しよう、というのが大きな目標になります。

また、エンジンのリアクティブ化と関連して、camel-core の API を明確化しようというのも目標の1つです。API の明確化によって、280以上あるコンポーネントはそのままで、コアのエンジンだけクラシックな実装とリアクティブな実装とを切り替えて使えるようになる、というメリットがあります。

実際には、camel-core も軽量とはいえ、既に内部実装はかなり複雑化してきているので、リアクティブに完全に書き換えるという試みはなかなか難しいようです。

その他、細かなところでは、現在 2.x 系で鋭意使われなくなったコンポーネントの `@Deprecated` 化が進められていますが、3.0 ではそれらはすべてゴソッと削除されます。コードベースがよりクリーンになるでしょう。

Comment: この回答に -1 している方がいますが、私の回答に誤りや不足があると思われるのなら、コメントや新たな回答でそれを提示いただけますか。もし、単に自分の質問に自分で回答しているのが気に食わないだけなら、これを読んで StackOverflow が自己回答を積極的に推奨しているのを理解しましょう。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: 自己回答は結構ですが、宣伝に見られるのではないでしょうか。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion SOではなく
 http://camel.apache.org/camel-30-ideas.html のページの日本語訳をQiitaにでも書かれた方が目的にかなうかと。

Comment: Apache CamelはOSSなので「製品の宣伝」というのは違和感があります。もちろん私の所属する会社にCamelを含んだ製品がありますが、その製品名はここでは一切言及していません。Qiitaは完全に別会社のサービスなので、ここでそちらを使うべき、というのも違和感があります。あくまでSOに値するか否かだけで十分でしょう。

Comment: OSSへの貢献を宣伝しているように見えますが、SOに値するものでしょうか。このQ&Aの目的がSOと沿うのかよく分かりません。

Comment: ちなみに、回答冒頭の一文は、元の質問をレビュアーの改善提案に基づき改善したのに伴い付けたものです。そこを宣伝したい意図はありません。

Comment: @htb この議論にご参加いただいているのであれば、ぜひこちらのメタ質問での議論にもご参加いただければと思います。
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2591/の次期メジャーバージョンアップの目玉機能は何か-という質問は主観的か

Comment: 「宣伝と見る人がいますよ」という視点の提供であり、そうでないなら結構ではないでしょうか。人の見方の話ですから、議論したとしても不毛です。